# How do I use jquery plugins with browserify?

Tags: jquery, node.js, jquery-ui, npm, browserify

I've installed jquery-ui via npm:

```
npm install jquery-ui --save
```

and I've come across the notion of shimming but I believe shims are no longer necessary.  I think my code should just work but it doesn't.  here's what I've got:

```
-- login.js --
require('jquery-ui');
require('jquery-ui/effect-shake');

module.exports = {
  init: function() {
    var elem = $(...); // some element on the page    
    elem.effect('shake');
  }
};
```

which gets browserified and included in my main page.  this is how the call gets made:

```
-- index.html --
<head>
<script src="browserified.js"></script>
<script>
  $().ready(function() {
    login.init();
  });
</script>
```

so the issue I have is that `.effect` is not a function.  am I requiring this incorrectly?

> browserified.js:5571 Uncaught TypeError: elem.effect is not a function

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I used to bind jquery-ui effect by triggering `.hide()` and then `.show()` to the element with options. so, it would be:

```
module.exports = {
  init: function() {
    var elem = $(...); // some element on the page    
    elem.hide();
    elem.show({duration:300, easing:"shake"});
  }
};
```

Comment: sure, but my question is more broad.  I meant to understand why my approach is not working when I believe it should because today it's this module, tomorrow another one